# AutoIt write checkbox state to file

Tags: autoit

I have two checkboxes named `$Checkbox1` and `$Checkbox2`. Also I have a combo named `Combo1`. How can I make the program to create a file with custom name which saves state of the checkboxes and the combo on exit and reads it on startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is using .ini files, as these have functions built into AutoIt for reading and writing. Ini files are used as configuration files all over windows, the look like:

```
[SectionName]
KeyName=Value
```

The best way to save checkbox states is as `1` or `0` and then use the `Int()` function to make sure that you are getting the value you want. For the combo you can either save it as a string in the ini, or as the index of the selected item. You make that choice based on whether the user can type in values that aren't in the dropdown and use them.

See [IniRead](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/IniRead.htm) and [IniWrite](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/IniWrite.htm) for more information.

There are some other alternatives, such as the registry, which in some cases are better options, but most of the time ini files are what we use.

Comment: This says nothing about how to read the checkbox state on strartup. I made an answer above about what I have done. The problem is to use the $Read1 variable I have used to change the checkbox state so if I closed it with a checkbox checked, it starts with the same checkbox checked. @Matt

Comment: Use IniRead to read the value, Int() to make sure AutoIt treats the value correctly, then an IF test and GUICtrlSetState to set the checked state.